# How to Override push into Array depending on the type?

Tags: arrays, typescript

How to Override push into Array depending on the type?

I am trying something like this

```
interface Foo{
    id:number
}
interface Bar{
    name:string
}
public func1( array_var: Foo[] | Bar []){
    if(array_var instanceof Array<Foo> ){
        array_var.push({id:10})
   }
   else if(array_var instanceof Array<Bar>){
       array_var.push({name:"Stack"})
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that types get **erased** when the TypeScript code is being transpiled to JavaScript, so you **cannot** have conditions that rely on the type. In JavaScript there is no such thing as `Array<T>`, there is just `Array`. For example, `[]` is *both* a `Foo[]` *and* a `Bar[]`, and we can't tell the difference between the two at runtime because there's no type information left.

In this case you have to leverage [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to convince the compiler that you've checked what can be checked:

```
interface Foo {
  id: number
}

interface Bar {
  name: string
}

function func1(array_var: Foo[] | Bar[]) {
  if (isFooArray(array_var)) {
    array_var.push({ id: 10 })
  }
  else {
    array_var.push({ name: "Stack" })
  }
}

function isFooArray(arr: any[]): arr is Foo[] {
  return arr[0].id !== undefined; // Possible implementation
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnLAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtLgL666iSyIoBCcUO+5cKhDIBnMFFABzRsxgUQCMMHQhkchQEYAFDyhwAngH0AbjzIZ0AbQC6yAD7JuUGwEo+BYDGRbgIiwEEoPX0dIIMTHhc3PAICXXDTKAA6AAcKEQALLWxCUmQNAAZkBhd+JgIIABsRFBjY+KNE1PSsnJBBYWQAIgBlMEQAay7i0oImJlx1RWVVXwCwkN0yOBB9V2WgwhE0TBt3ZCgIMAooVV1LAusk4mQAQgBee+R5IggYUAgiAG5kAHpf5AABXQIhEwBolRQwCoKUhQnAcCUKkYQA)

It works with a special function which you have to write the implementation, and TypeScript considers that the return value of that function (a boolean) represents the result of the `arr is Foo[]` expression. That helps it narrow the types accordingly. Note again per the first paragraph that you need some tangible runtime value to operate on: you'll have to make a decision as the developer on how to handle the empty array case.

I wrote an example implementation of it but you could write anything inside that [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) function.

Comment: Probably worth noting that `[]` is both `Foo[]` and `Bar[]` and there's no way do discriminate it at runtime... unless you do something like add a property to the arrays to do so.

Comment: That is precisely what I tried to explain in my first sentence. `Array` = `[]` and `Array<T>` = `Foo[]` or `Bar[]`

Comment: Yeah, *I* understand that implication but somebody who would ask this question probably wouldn't. Justing pointing it out, you're not at all wrong and I did upvote.

Comment: OK I (or you) can still edit if you feel like it's clearer for everyone

Comment: I edited, please rollback or doctor it up yourself if it doesn't suit.

Comment: Looks good to me, thanks for contributing!